# How can I increase the global font size past 20pt?

Tags: fontsize

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum*
\end{document}
```

I would like to set the font size to something like 30,
but it looks like 20 is the highest for extrarticle package, is there anything I can do to set the global font size even higher?

Comment: The proposed duplicate seems to answer the question for up to 20pt, but not for even larger sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the `fontsize` package, which is simply a "KOMA-free" version of `scrextend`, with few new features.  With the `fontsize` option the `\baselineskip` is automatically set to `1.2<fontsize>`. (In the following example: 1.2*30.2=36,24):

```
\usepackage[fontsize=30.2pt]{fontsize}
```

If you prefer you can set any value of `\baselineskip`, for example, through:

```
\changefontsize[35]{30.2}
```

The `\baselineskip` is set by the first optional argument and must be grater than or equal to the font size given in the second argument.

**MWE:**

You can use the font you prefer but if the font has optical sizes (for example Latin Modern), unusual things can happen: some larger sizes may appear smaller (see the documentation for details). The example below uses the Cochineal typeface:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
% a smoothly scalabel font is recommended
\usepackage{cochineal}
\usepackage[fontsize=30.2pt]{fontsize}
% FOR BETTER TUNING:
%\changefontsize[35]{30.2}
% #1: baseline skip
% #2: font size

\begin{document}

\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class provides a wide range of font sizes: 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt, 25pt, 30pt, 36pt, 48pt, 60pt. For sizes above 14pt it is best to also use the class option `extrafontsizes` which indicates scaleable fonts. So for a 20pt font:

```
\documentclass[20pt,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
```